# Animating a Clip-Path in React-Native View

Tags: animation, react-native

Basically I have an opaque View covering a screen, and I want to build an animation that is something like a (perfect circular) hole in the view forming in the center (so to reveal whats underneath) and expanding outwards.

I'm thinking that there could be a few creative ways to get this done, and that perhaps the most corresponding CSS property to play with would be 'clip-path'. If that is the case, I don't believe ReactNative Views offer that, and 3rd party libraries w/ SVG & clipping features seem like they wouldn't play well with Animating the effect.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg !

The library supports SVG's better and allows you to animate with Clip-path!